# count on a Boolean variable

Tags: python, dataframe, count, boolean

I have a dataframe (events) having several columns: id, ...,click,... The column "click" is a Boolean variable which has value of 'True' or 'False'. I use the code in Python below in order to count the number of 'True' for each individual "id":

`click_yes = events.groupby("id")["click"].count(True).reset_index()`

It came out an error: `TypeError: count() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

---

Example Output:

If the case is like this original dataframe:

```
   id  click
0   0   True
1   1   False
2   1   True
3   1   True
4   2   True
5   2   False
6   3   False
```

I want the result is a new dataframe, like this (count on the number of 'True'):

```
   id  click_count
0   0   1
1   1   2
2   2   1
3   3   0
```

How to modify my following code (not working) or write a new code to make my expectation happen?

click_yes = events.groupby("id")["click"].count(True).reset_index()
Thanks !!!

What is the right way to do this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sum()` instead - since `True` value is 1 and `False` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> sum(map(bool,[True, True, False, False, False, True]))
3
```

> Answer is 3, because **True == 1**

or only Sum:

```
>>> sum([True, True, False, False, False, True])
3
```

Or using count():

```
lst = [True, True, False, False, False, True] 
print(count(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using panda dataframes, so I've added a quick approach. BTW: Actually your use of `count` is wrong. It can only return the length of something (e. g. a list) but can't be used as a filter.

As you have added the desired output i now understand what you try to achieve. I have added a new snippet. Again I filter for 'True' Values. In the next line I start summing lines depending on it's column content.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create your list
# initialize list of lists
data = [ [0, True], [1, False], [1, True], [5, True], [2, True], 
         [2, False], [3, False], [2, True], [4, False], [1, True],
         [6, True], [2, True]]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'click'])
df = df.sort_values(by=['id'])


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# Filter for key value true
df = df[df.click == True]
# Merge lines depending of it's column content
filtered =  df.groupby('id').agg({ 'click':'sum'}).reset_index()
# If we need it, rename the column
filtered = filtered.rename(columns={"click": "click_count"})


# Print out the list
print(filtered)
```

If this is your input (dataframe):

```sh
    id  click
0    0   True
1    1  False
2    1   True
9    1   True
4    2   True
5    2  False
7    2   True
11   2   True
6    3  False
8    4  False
3    5   True
10   6   True
```

with the snippet you will get the following output:

```sh
    id  click_count
0   0          1.0
1   1          2.0
2   2          3.0
3   5          1.0
4   6          1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers! Appreciate it!

If the case is like this:

Original dataframe:

```
   id  click
0   0   True
1   1   False
2   1   True
3   1   True
4   2   True
5   2   False
6   3   False
```

I want the result is a new dataframe, like this (count on the number of 'True'):

```
   id  click_count
0   0   1
1   1   2
2   2   1
3   3   0
```

How to modify my following code (not working) or write a new code to make my expectation happen?

```
click_yes = events.groupby("id")["click"].count(True).reset_index()
```

Thanks !!!